# Flutter Type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

**Problem**

I'm new to flutter and right now I'm creating a delivery app.

The customer adds products in his cart, now I want to send this table of products chosen by the customer to the server to make his order and I have an error:

```
_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

> This is my class **CartItem**

```
class CartItem {
  String id, name, count, price, image;
  CartItem(this.id, this.name, this.count, this.price, this.image);
}
```

> Here I add the product to the cart

```
List cart = [];

addItemCart(Food item) {
    adjustPrice(item.price, true);

    for (int i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
      if (cart[i].name == item.name) {
        setState(() {
          cart[i].count = (int.parse(cart[i].count) + 1).toString();
          adjustScroll(i);
        });
        return;
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      cart.add(new CartItem(item.id, item.name, '1', item.price.toString(), item.image));
      adjustScroll(cart.length - 1);
    });
  }
```

> At this level where I get the error when I send to the server

```
payOnDelivery(
    adresseId,
    items,
    price,
    deliveryFee,
    tvaFee,
    finalPrice,
    paymentMode,
    devise,
  ) async {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreference = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = sharedPreference.getString('token');
    var header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'};

    Map data = {
      'adresseId': adresseId,
      'items': items,
      'price': price.toString(),
      'deliveryFee': deliveryFee.toString(),
      'tvaFee': tvaFee.toString(),
      'finalPrice': finalPrice.toString(),
      'paymentMode': paymentMode,
      'devise': devise
    };

    var jsonResponse;
    var response = await http.post(url + 'order/add/', body: data, headers: header);

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);

      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
        isLogged = true;
        cart = [];
      });
    } else {
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);

      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

[image: The list I want to send to the server (in image)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after several searches, I should just encode my List items in json by doing this:

```
var item = jsonEncode(items);

Map<String ,String> data = {
  'adresseId': adresseId,
  'items': item
  'price': price.toString(),
  'deliveryFee': deliveryFee.toString(),
  'tvaFee': tvaFee.toString(),
  'finalPrice': finalPrice.toString(),
  'paymentMode': paymentMode,
  'devise': devise
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Post only take Map<String,String> in body but you are using  
 Map<String,dynamic> that's why you  getting this error .In your   
 Map<String,dynamic>   items  list is dynamic type you need to  encode it


 Map<String ,String> data = {
  'adresseId': adresseId,
  'items': json.encode(items)
  'price': price.toString(),
  'deliveryFee': deliveryFee.toString(),
  'tvaFee': tvaFee.toString(),
  'finalPrice': finalPrice.toString(),
  'paymentMode': paymentMode,
  'devise': devise
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your message, I tried that but I got this message again: Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'CartItem'

Comment: json. encode(items.map((value) => value.tojson()).toList())

and create 

tojson() method inside your  CartItem class .Try with this

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just found the solution, by just doing var item = jsonEncode(items);